# What is the probability? (illustrated example)

Tags: probability

**edit:** Here is a short background for my question. I'm looking for the probability that *at least two operators* has made the same choice, thereby "matching". I've provided a sketch of the problem and this is my thought process and conclusions drawn from the sketch:

An operator is hired to operate a light diode. Each particular hour he can decide to switch it on or off. The likelihood of the operator deciding to switch it on is 50%.

A new operator is hired by the same rules to operate another light diode, the probability of at least two diodes being switched on at a particular hour is $\frac14, 25$%

Yet another third operator is hired, the probability of at least two diodes being switched on is now up to $\frac48,50$%

I have three questions:

Q1: What is the probability of at least two diodes being switched on at the same time when 4 operators are hired?

Q2: How many operators do you need to hire for the probability to be at least 90%?

Q3: If the probability that the operator switch on the diode is not $\frac12$ but instead $\frac1{16}$, how would this be accounted for in the equation?

**edit:** To find the number of possible states i guessed that if there are *n* operators, the possible states are $n^2$. This results in 2 operators having 4 possible states, 3 operators having 9 states and 4 operators having 16 states. However, when sketching it out it is clear that 3 operators only has 8 states. So something is wrong (I found out in the answer provided below that I mistakenly switched position of the base and the exponent, the correct way to calculate the states are $2^n$, not $n^2$)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Are you looking for the probability of *exactly* two diodes being switched on at the same time, or *at least* two diodes?

Comment: Thank you for recognising that this is my first post here. 
I’m looking for two or more diodes being lit.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the question is updated, I hope this is closer to the quality standards of the forum. Appreciate the input and let me know if further clarification is needed.

Comment: Yes, it is quite better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $n$ operators, there are $2^n$ different ways the diodes can be lit, each with probability $(1/2)^n$. In how many of these scenarios are fewer than two diodes lit? There's one scenario in which no diodes are lit, and $n$ scenarios in which exactly one diode is lit. Subtracting these cases out gives probability $1 - \frac{n+1}{2^n}$ that at least two diodes are lit when there are $n$ operators. Plug in $n=4$ to solve Q1. Experiment with your calculator for different $n$ to solve Q2.

Comment: That’s a well formulated answer! Thank you. Let’s say that the probability of a diode being lit is 1/4 instead of 1/2, how would you account for that?